# Laravel Echo Server and net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR on https version

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, redis, socket.io

I am using laravel 5.8 on my nginx server with laravel echo server, socket.io and redis.

My site was working till yesterday with no error but today it has been giving me socket errors such as:

```
GET https://example.com:6001/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NHtNFvZ net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

This my laravel-echo-server.json file:

```
{
    "authHost": "http://localhost:8000",
    "authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
    "clients": [
        {
            "appId": "123",
            "key": "123"
        }
    ],
    "database": "redis",
    "databaseConfig": {
        "redis": {
            "port": "6379",
            "host": "127.0.0.1"
        },
        "sqlite": {
            "databasePath": "/database/laravel-echo-server.sqlite"
        }
    },
    "devMode": true,
    "host": null,
    "port": "6001",
    "protocol": "http",
    "socketio": {},
    "sslCertPath": "",
    "sslKeyPath": "",
    "sslCertChainPath": "",
    "sslPassphrase": "",
    "apiOriginAllow": {
        "allowCors": true,
        "allowOrigin": "http://localhost:80",
        "allowMethods": "GET, POST",
        "allowHeaders": "Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Authorization, X-CSRF-TOKEN, X-Socket-Id"
    }
}
```

First I was encountered with `ERR_CRT_DATE_INVALID` error but later `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`.

I have restarted echo worker using `sudo supervisorctl restart echo-server:*` but still same issue.

Answer (score 3):

Finally I have resolved this issue.

I added :

`"authHost": "https://localhost:8000",`

`"protocol": "https",`

`"sslCertPath": "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem",`

`"sslKeyPath": "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem",`

in my laravel-echo-server.json file and restarted the echo server worker process using `sudo supervisorctl restart echo-server:*`

It might help someone in future.